# React setState based on component's rendered height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am making a component which should set a class based on the actual height of a component. For example:

Height > `maxHeight`:
`<div className='greater-than-max-height' />`

Height <= `maxHeight`:
`<div className='less-than-max-height' />`

The height of the component is only known in `componentDidMount`. Doing a setState in `componentDidMount` is not recommended as it will cause a re-render. How do you solve this?

Comment: You still need a re-render anyway, or how can you render the `div` with the className you want

Comment: Yes, but how to do it? Doing a `setState` in the `componentDidMount` is the only way?

Comment: Currently that's the only way I can imagine, maybe there is a better solution..

Comment: Another solution which I don't like is to manipulate the real DOM in `componentDidMount`. I have to say the performance may be better, but.. I just don't like

Comment: @CodinCat even I don't want to manipulate the DOM directly. `setState` looks like the only alternative.

Comment: @CodinCat turns out the `setState` is batched internally by react. Since I had a lot of components, calling `setState` for each was my primary concern. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution, yes just put the `setState` in `componentDidMount`. Because you need a re-render anyway. For a simple component, a re-render is not that expensive.

But if your component structure is complex and some of the children need computations, it's better to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` (or simply use `PureComponent`) in the child components.

Another solution is to manipulate the real DOM directly. It looks dirty but you get the best performance (you can guarantee that there is no unnecessary component renders nor DOM updates)

```
componentDidMount() {
  const height = getHeight()
  const div = document.getElementById('yourDivId')
  if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
    div.className = 'greater-than-max-height'
  } else {
    div.className = 'less-than-max-height'
  }
}
```

Note that if your component may update and change its height and you want to update the className, you'll also need to do this in `componentDidUpdate` (both solutions need to)

You can extract a function for that:

```
updateDivClass() {
  const height = getHeight()
  const div = document.getElementById('yourDivId')
  if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
    div.className = 'greater-than-max-height'
  } else {
    div.className = 'less-than-max-height'
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateDivClass()
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.updateDivClass()
}
```